# Creating tables with multiple authors, books and categories

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently learning database for an upcoming school semester, So I'm practicing with the books I currently have.  I have books by multiple authors and authors with multiple books.  Also books with multiple categories.

So I made three tables.  A books table (with all the books information, including the author), an authors table (with the authors name, address, ect) and a categories table (since some books have multiple categories).  Since some books have multiple authors and some authors have multiple books, I made a junction table called AuthorsBooks and filled it with information.  By best practice, is it ok to NOT put authors with only one book in that (AuthorsBooks) table?  Also, I created a BooksCategory junction table and put the books with multiple categories into that table.  What would be the best way to link those two tables?  By book title?   Thanks.

Comment: Would be good if you provided the Entity Relationship Diagram with your question.

Comment: You don't want an author column  in the books table, You find the author or authors of a book by going through the junction, or linking, table.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Ah yeah I was thinking about that earlier.  Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general your approach sounds correct with a few exceptions.

> So I made three tables

Here's my count, based on your descriptions:

- Authors
- Books
- Categories
- AuthorsBooks
- BooksCategories

> A books table (with all the books information, including the author)

This is incorrect.  At the point you realized you need AuthorsBooks, there is no reason to have author as part of the Books table.  Any column(s) you used to implement that should be removed from Books.

> By best practice, is it ok to NOT put authors with only one book in
>   that (AuthorsBooks) table?

Absolutely not.  You created the right structure with AuthorsBooks.  It supports any number of authors for a book.

> Also, I created a BooksCategory junction table and put the books with
>   multiple categories into that table. What would be the best way to
>   link those two tables?

By Keys.  Every table should have a primary key, and in your case the keys should be integers that get incremented with each new row.

Here's an outline of the table structure and standard naming.

```
Books
-----
id integer auto_increment primary key 
title varchar(150)

Categories
----------
id integer auto_increment primary key
name varchar(60)

BooksCategories
---------------
books_id  integer primary key (foreign key for Books.id)
categories_id integer primary key (foreign key for Categories.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was thinking about including the authors with only one book in the books table, then having the AuthorsBooks filled with only the authors with multiple books and the books with multiple authors, but I can see how that would be confusing, so I'll just include all authors (authorID) as a key) with their respective books (booksID) in the AuthorsBooks table.

Comment: Again, thanks you very much for your reply.  For future reference, if I were to look up the book and its categories would it be something like.. SELECT book_title, category FROM Books JOIN BooksCategories USING (books_id) JOIN Categories USING (categories_id)?

Comment: Basically yes, although you specify both sides of the join in the statement.  You also want to alias all the tables.  Also, I don't know if you did this, but don't  name the 'title' in the book table 'book_title'.  It's superfluous and just adds length to the names. Just call the title of a book 'title'.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: So a join would be something like:  `SELECT title, category FROM Books b JOIN BooksCategories bc ON (bc.books_id = b.id) JOIN Categories c ON (c.id = bc.categories_id)`  Just note you will get a row for every category.